# Eigenvalue perturbation under sparse perturbations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, perturbation-theory

Let $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ be an irreducible matrix whose entries are in $\{0,1\}$, and let $\lambda_1(A)$ be the eigenvalue with the largest magnitude. By Perron–Frobenius theorem, we know that $\lambda_1(A) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, define the matrix $B = \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ to be a matrix satisfying the following conditions:

1. $B$ has at most $t$ ones, where $t$ should be regarded as a small constant, e.g. 2.
2. If $B_{i,j} = 1$, then $A_{i,j} = 0$.
3. $A+B$ is irreducible.

I am interested in estimating $\lambda_1(A+B)$. The way I had in mind is the following (basically using some perturbation theory). First, define the function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(\epsilon) = \lambda_1(A + \epsilon B)$.
Then, it might be possible to write $f$ as a power series around $0$, and use this series up to some order as an estimation.

All of this is pretty standard, but it is usually used in order to estimate $f$ around $0$, whereas I am interested in estimating $f$ at $1$. The reason I thought this method might still work is that $B$ is very sparse, and so even when $\epsilon = 1$, the perturbation is still "small" in some sense.  Are there any known results of this type?

EDIT: as shown in an answer, the conjecture below is wrong. The question that still remains is estimating $\lambda_1(A+B)$.

What seem to be the case is (and if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, it seems even more plausible) that $\lambda_1(A+B) \approx \lambda_1(A) + O(\frac{t}{n})$.

Comment: Just an idea, not sure whether it's useful - maybe one can devise a change of basis which turns your sparse $B$ into a small $B$, i.e., it isn't necessarily sparse anymore, but the entries are all bounded by some small number. Then this becomes a more standard perturbation problem.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt thank you. Do you know of any example of this type?

Comment: A really simple case would be something like $B$ with all elements zero except $B_{1,1} =1$. Then if you transform with a $U$ that has all elements in the first row equal to $\epsilon $, $U^{\dagger } BU$ is a matrix with all elements equal to $\epsilon^{2} $. As long as your $t$ is smaller than your $n$, you might have enough freedom for such operations not to interfere with each other too much.

Comment: Related bound that might be of use to you: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243215/upper-bound-on-the-difference-between-two-perron-frobenious-eigen-values

Comment: Not an answer, but let me note that there is some published study of the behavior of eigenvalues under low-*rank* perturbation (and your $B$ has rank at most $t$); see e.g. https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479802417118 . But it mostly focuses on the behavior of "breaking" large Jordan blocks, because that's the main invariant there.

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture is not true.  Let $A_{ij}=1$ iff $i=j\pm 1$.  Let $B$ be diagonal, with one nonzero entry in the $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$-th position.  Then, $\lambda_1(A)<2$.  (If we had instead taken $A_{ij}=1$ iff $i=j\pm 1 \mod n$ then $\lambda_1(A)=2$). Meanwhile, $\lambda_1(A+B)$ is monotonically increasing in $n$, and one may verify explicitly that $\lambda_1(A+B)$ is $>2$ for large enough $n$, indeed fairly small $n$ suffice.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the question and remove this conjecture from it.

Comment: This example is quite interesting! I believe that it's provable that $\lambda_1(A_n + B_n) \rightarrow 2.5$ for your example, which seems to yield a limiting difference $\lambda_1(A_n + B_n) - \lambda_1(A_n) \rightarrow 0.5$ for $B_n$ with a single $1$ ($t = 1$ in the OP's notation). I wonder whether $0.5$ is an optimal upper bound for $t = 1$?

Comment: Sorry to comment on a comment, but I guess that if $A, B$ are symmetric, then $\lambda_1(A + B) - \lambda_1(A) \leq 1$ for $t = 1$ by Weyl's inequality (which states that $\lambda_1(A + B) \leq \lambda_1(A) + \lambda_1(B)$, and $\lambda_1(B) \leq 1$ trivially. I suspect this might hold in greater generality, but don't see a proof.

Comment: @RonniePavlov I don't think this type of bounds can be generalized beyond normal matrices. Eigenvalues of symmetric (or normal) matrices are well-behaved, those of non-symmetric matrices aren't. For instance, perturbation results show that (with suitable ordering) $|\lambda_i(A+E) - \lambda_i(A) |\leq \kappa(V) ||E||$, where $\kappa(V)$ is the condition number of (a choice for) the eigenvector matrix. This condition number is 1 for symmetric or normal matrices but can be arbitrarily high in general.